# DIA SDK SymTagEnum value

Tags: c++, dia-sdk

I'm currently dumping a lot of information from a PDB file I retrieve using the DIA SDK to an XML file so that I can then use that information to display stuff about the structure of the project etc.

For naming the XML nodes, I have a trivial function that translates the value of the enum to a string which is then used for the node:

```
string symTagTypeToString(DWORD type) {

string symTagTypename = "";

switch(type) {
case SymTagNull:
    symTagTypename = "null";
    break;
case SymTagExe:
    symTagTypename = "exe";
    break;
case SymTagCompiland:
    symTagTypename = "compiland";
    break;
case SymTagCompilandDetails:
    symTagTypename = "compilandDetails";
    break;
case SymTagCompilandEnv:
    symTagTypename = "compilandEnvironmentVar";
    break;
case SymTagFunction:
    symTagTypename = "function";
    break;
case SymTagBlock:
    symTagTypename = "block";
    break;
case SymTagData:
    symTagTypename = "data";
    break;
case SymTagAnnotation:
    symTagTypename = "annotation";
    break;
case SymTagLabel:
    symTagTypename = "label";
    break;
case SymTagPublicSymbol:
    symTagTypename = "publicSymbol";
    break;
case SymTagUDT:
    symTagTypename = "userDefinedType";
    break;
case SymTagEnum:
    symTagTypename = "enumerator";
    break;
case SymTagFunctionType:
    symTagTypename = "functionType";
    break;
case SymTagPointerType:
    symTagTypename = "pointer";
    break;
case SymTagArrayType:
    symTagTypename = "array";
    break;
case SymTagBaseType:
    symTagTypename = "baseType";
    break;
case SymTagTypedef:
    symTagTypename = "typedef";
    break;
case SymTagBaseClass:
    symTagTypename = "baseClass";
    break;
case SymTagFriend:
    symTagTypename = "friend";
    break;
case SymTagFunctionArgType:
    symTagTypename = "functionArgumentType";
    break;
case SymTagFuncDebugStart:
    symTagTypename = "funcDebugStart";
    break;
case SymTagFuncDebugEnd:
    symTagTypename = "funcDebugEnd";
    break;
case SymTagUsingNamespace:
    symTagTypename = "usingNamespace";
    break;
case SymTagVTableShape:
    symTagTypename = "vTableShape";
    break;
case SymTagVTable:
    symTagTypename = "vTable";
    break;
case SymTagCustom:
    symTagTypename = "custom";
    break;
case SymTagThunk:
    symTagTypename = "thunk";
    break;
case SymTagCustomType:
    symTagTypename = "customType";
    break;
case SymTagManagedType:
    symTagTypename = "managedType";
    break;
case SymTagDimension:
    symTagTypename = "dimension";
    break;
default:
    ostringstream s;
    s << "other" << type;
    symTagTypename = s.str();
    break;
}

return symTagTypename;
}
```

This function encompasses all values listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bkedss5f.aspx

Now, for dumping the DIA information, I basically just recurse down the children of all symbols I get using `pGlobal->findChildren(SymTagUDT, NULL, nsCaseSensitive, &pIDiaEnumSymbols)`. The curious part is that the resulting XML contains a lot of stuff that looks like this:

```
<function name="consumer::main">
  <funcDebugStart name="unknown">
  </funcDebugStart>
  <funcDebugEnd name="unknown">
  </funcDebugEnd>
  <data name="">
  </data>
  <data name="">
  </data>
  <data name="">
  </data>
  <data name="this">
  </data>
  <data name="c">
  </data>
  <other31 name="unknown">
  </other31>
  <other31 name="unknown">
  </other31>
  <other31 name="unknown">
  </other31>
  <other31 name="unknown">
  </other31>
  <other31 name="unknown">
  </other31>
  <other31 name="unknown">
  </other31>
  <other31 name="unknown">
  </other31>
  <other31 name="unknown">
  </other31>
 </function>
```

Now, nevermind the empty name information and stuff, that's all pretty unfinished so far. I'd just really like to know what kind of symbol has a **symTag of 31**. The enumerator seems to contain 31 elements, so values from 0 to 30 should be valid. Does anybody have any idea what this 31 could be? The function in question looks like this:

```
 void main()
 {
   char c;
   cout << endl << endl;

   while (true) {
     in->read(c);
     cout << c << flush;

     if (in->num_available() == 1)
   cout << "<1>" << flush;
     if (in->num_available() == 9)
   cout << "<9>" << flush;
   }
 }
```

It's part of the SystemC fifo example project. Nothing too fancy, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the DIA SDK version that's shipped with VS2010, the two SymTagEnum values SymTagCallSite and SymTagMax have been added (although they have not been included in the documentation yet). Although I still haven't got really an idea about the semantics those values stand for, this definitely explains the values I'm getting.